# How to prevent React Native Android Webview from running Youtube in the background?

Tags: android, webview, react-native

My app was rejected in play store for "make sure it doesn't enable background play of YouTube videos". I used the basic Webview component and loaded a youtube page. After playing the youtube movie, and going back to home page, the youtube movie keeps on playing in the background.

How do I get a handle to pause the Webview when the app gets paused?

Comment: Just a follow up... I have the exact same issue and had my app rejected for this reason. Could you release the full code to your custom component.

Comment: @AlexHarrison did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, see custom MyReactWebview answer below

Answer (score 10):

You could use **AppState** from react-native: [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html).

And show the webview (which contains your YouTube embed) only if the app state is '**active**'

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {AppState, WebView} from 'react-native'

class AppStateExample extends Component {

  state = {
      appState: AppState.currentState
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {        
      this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }

  render() {

    return (

      {this.state.appState == 'active' &&
           <WebView />
      }

    )

  }

}
```

This is good if you are working with **Expo**, no need to touch any native code.

Comment: This works, but the side effect is that users who switch to other screens and then return are forced to start over in the video (once you destroy the webview, it doesn't save your position).

Comment: @eculeus this is true.  Instead, you can use the youtube iframe api to pause the video.

Comment: {this.state.appState == 'active' &&  <webview/>} where i find this approach of render data in react native any docs ?

Comment: @Abhiode The technique is called short-circuit evaluation, https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: @eculeus by default if we play a youtube video usin react-native-web-view will it continue playing media even if app is in background or phone is in locked state?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so i ended up creating my own `MyReactWebViewManager`:

```
public class MyReactWebViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<WebView> {

private static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTMyWebView";

....
```

And in it, i created `MyReactWebView` with the following onHostPause override:

```
private static class MyReactWebView extends WebView implements LifecycleEventListener { 
    ...

    @Override
    public void onHostResume() {
        // do nothing
        Log.i(REACT_CLASS,"onHostResume");
        this.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostPause() {
        // do nothing
        Log.i(REACT_CLASS,"onHostPause");
        this.onPause();
    }
```

Hopefully, this will be handled by react-native in the future.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you did this? I have the exact same issue

Comment: @Greg I hope you already solved it, but if this is not the case, you need to required the native module and export it as a JavaScript module: module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTMyWebView', null); Reffer to [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this prop to the web view

mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}

```
 <WebView
   mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
 />
```

Comment: Doubt this will work.  According to the docs `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` already defaults to true.