# React Native disable Youtube playback on lock screen

Tags: android, webview, react-native, google-play

My app was rejected from `Play Store` because when playing a `Youtube` video, it continues to play after you lock the screen.

My app loads an `API` which will put a Youtube link in a `WebView`

I've been searching on Google but haven't found anything that could help me.. How can I make sure the Webview pauses on lock?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent React Native Android Webview from running Youtube in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382935/how-to-prevent-react-native-android-webview-from-running-youtube-in-the-backgrou)

Comment: did you find the solution, i got the same on

Comment: @JamesNguyen Unfortunately I didn't.. What I did as an alternative is to link the video to Youtube. I used a thumbnail with play button, people click the video and they will be redirected to Youtube.

Comment: not lucky for me. Video is an iframe with a youtube link, so i can not do like you.

Comment: @JamesNguyen It's also an embedded code for me, but I slice the url part out of the code and use that to link to the video.