# React Native play sound on screen lock or background

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I would like play YouTube video on React Native app and enable sound when screen is locked or app in background.

Is it possible on React Native ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 0):

No , it's not "possible" on react native. There are some modules that allow a background timer or even background tasks in this post you will find manky https://stackoverflow.com/a/50545627/10205629 , but to keep the sound of the webview playing in the background (i assume that you are using a webview to play youtube videos), i don't know if it is a bug or the way the webview is supposed to work, but it will play on the lock screen and on the home screen until the app is killed/removed from ram like
 [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847720/react-native-disable-youtube-playback-on-lock-screen)

or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382935/how-to-prevent-react-native-android-webview-from-running-youtube-in-the-backgrou)

Comment: Thank you Valda :) I use react-native-youtube, but after try in WebView, the video stop is screen is locked or change app :/

Comment: @StéphaneR. Did you found any solution i am using reactnative webview and trying to achieve background playback?