# how to add a youtube link to expo-av lib?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building an app using react native expo , I have a screen where I should add a youtube link to Video component of expo-av , the default url in expo example is working fine but replacing it with any youtube url does not work , the screen just remains empty and no errors in the console, could you please help here my code :

```
 <Video
        ref={video}
        style={{ width: 300, height: 200 }}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaEG2aWJnZ8',
        }}
        posterStyle={{
          resizeMode: 'cover',
        }}
        usePoster={false}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode='contain'
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => setStatus(() => status)}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

Expo Video does not support direct playback of YouTube URLs.

As suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44916378/16492542) answer:

> You can either eject the project and install the [react-native-youtube](https://github.com/davidohayon669/react-native-youtube) library or load your videos from a WebView like this:
>
> ```
> <WebView
>     style={{flex:1}}
>     javaScriptEnabled={true}
>     source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZZ5LpwO-An4?rel=0&autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0'}}
> </WebView>
> ```